# Is the 'Gatwick drones' question on-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, off-topic, on-topic, vote-to-close

[Are there any photos or videos of the drones at Gatwick?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/58382/14897)

The question asks for photos, and if no photos exist, asks about the reliability of eyewitnesses/news.

Is it on-topic, or should it be closed?

Answer (score 4):

IMO **it should be closed;** it is off-topic for more than 1 reason:

1. Resource finding, if no photo(s), then:
2. Opinion based, and lastly:
3. Not aviation related – *whaaaaat?!*

It is an event, that happened to an airport, that disrupted air travel.

The same event can happen to a sensitive government building, disrupt road traffic, and also make the news.

The question revolves around *an* event and its related conspiracies/theories, which makes it a better fit for Skeptics.SE.

It is of no value to aviation. A better question (for Aviation.SE) that can stem from such an event can be: how do airport scan for and protect against drones?

Two years later, it was asked: [How do airports detect drones?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/84542/14897) :)

Just my 2¢, over to you.

Comment: I agree. I also thought "What has this got to do with Aviation?" but didnt say anything lest I get lots of "It happened at an airport!!!1 how can it NOT be about aviation?!?"

Comment: @Jamiec: I could have stopped at 2, but I had to get it out 